# Is there a mechanism for C++ like macros in haxe?

Tags: macros, compilation, haxe, conditional-compilation

in C++ I have macros like:

```cpp
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define dbgAssert(condition, message)/
    if(!(condition)){ implementation.Assert(message); }
#else
    #define dbgAssert(condition, message)
#endif
```

This approach is efficient as the condition is never tested if we're not in debug mode particularly when some of the conditions can be particularly heavy on CPU.

Is there a way to implement this type of one liners in Haxe?

This is a very simple example as there are some macros with a dozen conditional definitions (depending on multiple parameters) I can't efficiently maintain redundant redefinitions all over the place.

Here is a slightly more interesting system which allows me to always test for the simplest condition and add heavyer tests depending on the level:

```cpp
#if 4 == ASSERT4LEVEL
    #define lvlAssert4(conditionlvl1, conditionlvl2, conditionlvl3, conditionlvl4, message)/
    myAssert((conditionlvl1) && (conditionlvl2) && (conditionlvl3) && (conditionlvl4), message)
#elif 3 == ASSERT4LEVEL 
    #define lvlAssert4(conditionlvl1, conditionlvl2, conditionlvl3, conditionlvl4, message)/
    myAssert((conditionlvl1) && (conditionlvl2) && (conditionlvl3), message)
#elif 2 == ASSERT4LEVEL 
    #define lvlAssert4(conditionlvl1, conditionlvl2, conditionlvl3, conditionlvl4, message)/
    myAssert((conditionlvl1) && (conditionlvl2), message)
#else
    #define lvlAssert4(conditionlvl1, conditionlvl2, conditionlvl3, conditionlvl4, message)/
    myAssert((conditionlvl1), message)
#endif
```

How can I replicate this behavior without executing the conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frabbits answer is the correct one for this situation, but here is the macro version as well.

```
@:macro static public function dbgAssert(condition, message) {
     #if debug
     return macro if (!($condition)) { implementation.Assert($message); }
     #else
     return macro {};
     #end
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create 2 different functions based on the debug flag. The release function should be inline and should do nothing.

```
    class Debug {
        #if debug
        public static function assert (e:Bool) {
            if (!e) throw "assert";
        }
        #else
        public static inline function assert (e:Bool) {
            return;
        }
        #end

    }
```

You should also take a look at haxe macros, which can do a lot of powerful things during compilation time.